# Realm note based App not properly deleting the Correct Object

Tags: xcode, uitableview, realm, reloaddata

When a cell is deleted, the item at the end of the list takes the place of the item that just got deleted. This only happens when there are more than 3 items in the list.

In the gif below I delete numbers 3 and 4 which leaves me with numbers 1,2,5 in the simulator. **HOWEVER** in the Realm file I have numbers 1,2,4. I have no clue why it does this?

[image]

**Data Model**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Item: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""

}
```

**View Controller**

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ListViewController: UITableViewController {

let realm = try! Realm()
var itemArray : Results<Item>?

var item:Item?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.itemArray = realm.objects(Item.self)

}

@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var textField = UITextField()
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Item", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.red

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Item", style: .default) { (action) in

     let newItem = Item()
     newItem.name = textField.text!

        try! self.realm.write {

            self.realm.add(newItem)

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
        alertTextField.placeholder = "Create new item"
        textField = alertTextField

    }
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.itemArray!.count//Size of the Array
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath)//Asigns the Protocol Cell
    let data = self.itemArray![indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = data.name

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete { 
        if let item = itemArray?[indexPath.row] {

            try! self.realm.write {
                self.realm.delete(item)
            }
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are retrieving an unsorted result set from Realm, which as per documentation does not necessarily retain insertion order after deletions (basically when you remove `3`, then `5` is shifted in its place):

> Note that the order of Results is only guaranteed to stay consistent when the query is sorted. For performance reasons, insertion order is not guaranteed to be preserved.

So there are two things you can do:

1.) sort the result set

2.) instead of assuming you're only deleting a single object and otherwise have no movements of any sort, you can rely on Realm's own diffing + change set evaluation with a notification token so that you receive a change set for any possible change that happens to the result set.

> ```
> // see https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collection-notifications
> class ViewController: UITableViewController {
>     var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil
>
>     override func viewDidLoad() {
>         super.viewDidLoad()
>         let realm = try! Realm()
>         let results = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("age > 5")
>
>         // Observe Results Notifications
>         notificationToken = results.observe { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
>             guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
>             switch changes {
>             case .initial:
>                 // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
>                 tableView.reloadData()
>             case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
>                 // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
>                 tableView.beginUpdates()
>                 tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
>                                      with: .automatic)
>                 tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}),
>                                      with: .automatic)
>                 tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
>                                      with: .automatic)
>                 tableView.endUpdates()
>             case .error(let error):
>                 // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
>                 fatalError("\(error)")
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     deinit {
>         notificationToken?.invalidate()
>     }
> }
> ```